Does all men in Jannah get 2 wives from earth?
Regardless of status does all men in Jannah get at least one or as per an hadith 2 women of Earth?
What about the last person to enter Jannah and he is followed by his 2 wives, are these wives, hoors or people of Earth?
I am confused regarding various interpretations and hadiths.
Please simplify.
Referring:

Undoubtedly the believer will have more than two [wives] in Paradise, because of the report narrated in as-Sahihayn [al-Bukhari (3243) and Muslim (2838)] from Abu ‘Imran al-Jawzi, from Abu Bakr ibn ‘Abdillah ibn Qays, from his father, who said: The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “In Paradise the believer will have a tent made from a single hollowed-out pearl, sixty miles high (or wide), in which the believer will have wives and he will go around among them and they will not see one another.” (Hadi al-Arwah, p. 232)

Ibn al-Qayyim said:

there is no mention in the sahih hadiths of anything more than two wives, except what is mentioned in the hadith of Abu Musa, that “In Paradise the believer will have a tent made from a single hollowed-out pearl, sixty miles high (or wide), in which the believer will have wives and he will go around among them.”

I say: The last hadith was classed as sahih by ad-Diya.
According to the hadith of Abu Sa‘id in [Sahih] Muslim, which speaks of the lowest of the people of Paradise in status, he says:

“Then his two wives will enter upon him.”

Al-‘Iraqi (may Allah have mercy on him) said:

“The two wives will be from among the women of this world, and the wives in addition to that will be from among al-hur al-‘in.… From the other reports, it is clear that two wives is the minimum that the inhabitant of Paradise will have from among the women of this world, and the minimum number that he will have from among al-hur al-‘in is seventy. As for more than that, there will be no limit… at-Tirmidhi narrated from Thuwayr ibn Abi Fakhitah that Ibn ‘Umar (may Allah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “The lowest of the people of Paradise in status will be one who will look out on his gardens, wives, blessings, servants and concubines, the distance of one thousand years. The dearest of them to Allah will be the one who looks upon His Countenance morning and evening.” (Tarh at-Tathrib fi Sharh at-Taqrib, 8/270)

So are the wives from amongst people of this world or hoors?
Does a unmarried person also gets hoors or daughters of Adam(A.S)?
